# Cannot find Xamarin controls

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin in order to develop mobile applications with C#.

When I open `Main.xaml`, I cannot find any controls in the Visual Studio toolbox and the XML editor does not allow me to write anything. How do I fix this?

Comment: Probably, you see something like http://screencast.com/t/t5hJke8q ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I resolved it by going over to https://www.xamarin.com/download and downloading the installer directly. Once you run it, it detects missing components and updates / installs them for you.

Comment: I downloaded the installer, it installed everything except Windows SDK (gave me an error) and nothing has changed. I still cannot see the controls